# HighCharts : Is it possible to customize the colors of just one series like image?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts line graph. 
1st, this is my code.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
        text: 'title is Here',
      color: 'Red'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['3 month', '2 month', 'last month', 'this month']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
                lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: '#b6c4ce',
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: '#83e3be' // inherit from series
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 51.5, 36.4, 69.2]
    }]
});
```

In this graph, I wanna customize just 1 specific line in plotOptions.series
I wanna change line color from 'last month' to 'this month'.
How can I customize like below image?

[image]

Comment: check this doc https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones

Comment: Thanks! that's i wanna know~